# Joining hundreds of columns and column indexes into a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got what I hope is a unique/interesting problem for my first question on Stack Overflow!

I have data on skills assessments, currently in a very large pandas dataframe. Each row represents a student, and each column contains their scores for a particular skills assessment. There are about 200 skill assessments in total, with each student having a score in only a small subset of these assessments (1 - 20 scores is typical, but some students have more).

Example dataframe structure:

```
id    skill1  skill2  skill3  skill4  skill5 ....
1     10      50      NaN     3       NaN
2     Nan     10      2       70      NaN
3     23      NaN     45      NaN     5
```

I am attempting to get this data transformed into a space-delimited string for each student, in the following format, so that we can import it into a different datastore:

```
skill1:10 skill2:50 skill4:3
skill2:10 skill3:2 skill4:70
```

(notice how skills without assessments scores don't get added to the list)

I've created a lambda function to join all of these skill values with their column labels:

```
skillmerge = lambda row: ' '.join([str(row.index[i])+':'+str(row[i]) for i in range(0,len(row)) if row[i]!=np.nan])
```

When I created a single series (1 student) to test on, the lambda function takes less than a second to create the output string in my desired format. However, when I create a dataframe with just 2 rows (again for testing purposes), the function takes several minutes just to complete those 2 rows:

```
testing_df['combined_skills'] = testing_df.apply(skillmerge, axis=1)
```

Seeing as how I have a couple million students in this dataset, I am looking for way to make this process reliably work faster. Any thoughts on where I can fix this?

Thanks in advance for helping with my first SO question! :D

Comment: You could just calculate the `row.index[i]` before the list comprehension since the labels remain constant

Comment: Well, they don't exactly remain constant. The desired output format doesn't include skills for which there is no assessment score.

Comment: No, but your list comprehension will still test every value of `i` in `range(len(indices))` against `row[i] != np.nan`. So you could make a list of _every_ index beforehand, e.g. `my_index_list = [skill1, skill2,...skilln]` and then change `row.index[i]` to `my_index_list[i]`. It's not clear to me why runtime would explode with just adding 1 extra row.

Comment: doesn't this: `if row[i]!=np.nan]` handle that case for you?  If `skill3` is nan, it won't be included, but it is still `skill3`

Comment: Joel, that's exactly why I've included that condition. I think that I understand what you and roganjosh are saying about pre-computing the list, though. By pre-computing the list, Pandas doesn't have to compute it for each iteration.

Comment: Yes, not sure I said it clearly, but anything you can pull out of a loop should save you some time. -- test it

Comment: Upon further tweaking, pre-building the list is much faster, but now my lambda function prints skills when a NaN value, effectively ignoring my conditional check.

Comment: Um, that makes no sense to me, something else is going on. What would you have to tweek to make it work, when it should have been a direct substitute? (Side note on SO, you need to use @ before a user's name in comments for them to get a notification that you've replied to a specific person btw, but post author is always notified).

Comment: @roganjosh I am equally confused. It's the exact same code, except I replaced the row.index[i] with the pre-built list, and now it prints all skills, including those with NaN.

Comment: But I'm asking specifically what the "tweeking" was. Because if the replacement method actually _ran and gave the same output_ originally but with no difference in speed, then your tweek that sped it up significantly must have changed something else fundamental, which might now explain why NaN is being included. We can't see your implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `to_json` then fixing it

```
def to_str(x):
    return x.dropna().to_json(double_precision=0) \
            .replace('"', '').replace(',', ' ').strip("{}")

df.T.apply(to_str)
```

Or using list comprehension and `join`

```
def to_str(x):
    return " ".join(["{}:{}".format(k, int(v)) for k, v in x.dropna().iteritems()])

df.T.apply(to_str)
```

Both give

```
id
1    skill1:10 skill2:50 skill4:3
2    skill2:10 skill3:2 skill4:70
3    skill1:23 skill3:45 skill5:5
dtype: object
```

---

***Making your solution work***

```
skillmerge = lambda row: ' '.join([str(row.index[i])+':'+str(row[i]) for i in range(len(row)) if not np.isnan(row[i])])

df.T.apply(skillmerge)
```

Notice that `np.nan == np.nan` evaluates to `False`.  In order to test for `np.nan` use `np.isnan` or `pd.isnull` or `pd.notnull`.  This fact was throwing off your solution.  I replaced it with `not np.isnan` and it works.

I took the opportunity to do what I'd do because I like it better.

Comment: ... That's awesome, upvote. Are you able to give any insight into why the original approach was going crazy as this one is fundamentally different? Why `to_json`?

Comment: @roganjosh I just updated my post with an explanation on why the OP solution wasn't working.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you! As a sidnote, my System Monitor shows your approach to be much more memory efficient as well.

Comment: Appreciated. It's curious that OP explained that the initial code worked, but it was somehow taking a ridiculous amount of time to evaluate the list comprehension.

Comment: @roganjosh I've been experimenting with why it was taking so long, and I think it's just the size of the dataframe involved. I've got a machine with 8 cores, so I don't think that the clock speed on any single core is very high. I rewrote my code using the multiprocessing library and the solution by piRSquared and I can run the entire apply on the dataframe in less than 2 minutes now.

Comment: @MatthewBrugman even if the clock speed isn't very high, you shouldn't jump from < 1 second to > 1 minute by doubling the size of the problem (1 example row to 2).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ld = df.set_index('id').fillna("").to_dict(orient='records')
ll = [' '.join([ k +":"+ str(v) for k,v in x.iteritems() if v != "" ]) for x in ld ]
ll 

 ['skill2:50.0 skill1:10.0 skill4:3.0',
 'skill3:2.0 skill2:10.0 skill4:70.0',
 'skill3:45.0 skill1:23.0 skill5:5.0']
```